# sql query to list additional columns (without aggr() & groupby )

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Earlier today I had this question and solved it, now I am in a fix to list one more column (with ranking functions..  if possible)

My table for the vehicles is:

```
vehNo   tTime                     odo     address
ABC     2013-02-13 10:30:00       80       denver
ABC     2013-02-12 10:30:00       10       boston
ABC     2013-02-12 12:30:00       30       berlin
ABC     2013-02-13 01:30:00       40       montreal
ABC     2013-02-13 02:30:00       40       montreal
ABC     2013-02-13 03:30:00       40       montreal

XYZ     2013-02-13 03:33:00       44       houston
ABC     2013-02-13 04:30:00       60       madrid
ABC     2013-02-13 11:30:00       100      alaska
```

Currently the below query works fine (listing 3 columns between two time)

```
select vehNo, max(tTime) as [tTime], odo
from Table_3
where vehNo = 'ABC' and tTime between '2013-02-12 10:30:00' and '2013-02-13 10:30:00'
group by vehNo, odo
order by vehNo, odo;
```

So without aggregate() and group by can I have 'address' as the 4th and get the required result as

```
vehNo   tTime                     odo     address
ABC     2013-02-12 10:30:00       10     boston
ABC     2013-02-12 12:30:00       30     berlin
ABC     2013-02-13 03:30:00       40     montreal(time latest, ignoring 1:30 & 2:30)
ABC     2013-02-13 04:30:00       60     madrid
ABC     2013-02-13 10:30:00       80     denver
```

I'm running on SQL Server 2005, so is it possible to have ranking function..

Comment: If the address does not change for vehNo, odo then you can just add address to the group by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY vehNo, odo
                       ORDER BY tTime DESC) AS RowNum 
   FROM table_3
   where vehNo = 'ABC' 
     and tTime between '2013-02-12 10:30:00' 
                   and '2013-02-13 10:30:00'
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86f78/2)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [windowing/ranking functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) to get the result. There are two options that I can see either `row_number()` or `rank()`. When using the windowing function, you then use a `WHERE` clause to return only those rows with a rank of 1.

The `rank()` will return multiple rows in the event you have two entries for each `vehNo` and `address` at the same time. `row_number()` will return only the first row. So you will need to decide which function will be best for your situation:

```
select vehNo, tTime, odo, address
from 
(
  select vehNo, tTime, odo, address,
    rank() over(partition by vehNo, odo order by tTime desc) rnk
  from yourtable
  where vehNo = 'ABC' 
    and tTime between '2013-02-12 10:30:00' and '2013-02-13 10:30:00'
) d
where rnk = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0f74/8).

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE:

```
WITH ag 
(
    select vehNo, max(tTime) as [tTime], odo
    from Table_3
    where vehNo = 'ABC' 
      and tTime between '2013-02-12 10:30:00' 
                    and '2013-02-13 10:30:00'
    group by vehNo, odo
)
select vehNO, tTime, odo, T.address
from ag 
inner join ag on Table_3 T on ag.vehNo=T.vehNo
order by vehNo, odo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `row_number()` function?

```
select 
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY vehNo) AS period,
vehNo, max(tTime) as [tTime], odo
from Table_3
where vehNo = 'ABC' and tTime between '2013-02-12 10:30:00' and '2013-02-13 10:30:00'
group by vehNo, odo
order by vehNo, odo;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
MAX(address)
```

Even though it is a varchar you can still use MAX.